# CS1545 error with specific COM object properties

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

I am doing COM automation with a 3rd party library. When trying to access certain properties I need to use `obj.get_Property()` instead of `obj.Property`.

This seems to be happening only for properties of type *string* that have both a getter and a setter.

I would like to understand why C# can't handle these cases, and if there's anything I can do to address this.

**Edit - Additional info:**

- The automation target application ships with type libraries in .tlb format, which Visual Studio uses to produce interop libraries.
- The decompiled interop library of interest looks similar to this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using NS0;

namespace NS1
{
    [ComImport]
    [Guid("AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-000000000000")]
    [TypeLibType(1234)]
    public interface SpecialDocument : Document
    {
        //...
        [DispId(1234567890)]
        new string Name
        {
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
            [DispId(1234567890)]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
            get;
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
            [DispId(1234567890)]
            [param: In]
            [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
            set;
        }
        //...
        [DispId(1234567891)]
        new string FullName
        {
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
            [DispId(1234567891)]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
            get;
        }
        //...
        [DispId(1234567892)]
        new bool IsVisible
        {
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
            [DispId(1234567892)]
            get;
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
            [DispId(1234567892)]
            [param: In]
            set;
        }
    }
```

- In the code snippet above, of the 3 properties defined, only *Name* must be accessed with *get_Name* or *set_Name*. The other properties get accessed as one would expect in C#.
- Both *Name* and *FullName* are inherited from the parent class *Document*, defined in *NS0*, where they have the same definition.
- According to the documentation, all automation interfaces for the product derive from *IDispatch*.

**Edit - Adding repro steps:**

0. Acquire a license for FancySoft and install the product.
1. Start a new .NET 4.8 console project in VS 2022.
2. Import COM reference.
3. In Main, connect to the running COM server with `Marshal.GetActiveObject("FancySoft.Application");`
4. Navigate to a *SpecialDocument* instance, and attempt to read the document's *Name* property.
5. CS1545

**Edit - Additional info from the .TLB (extracted with oleview.exe):**

```
// From "dispinterface Document":
[
  uuid(AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-111111111111),
  helpcontext(0x00001111),
  dual
]
dispinterface Document {
    properties:
    methods:
        // ...
        [id(0x76543210), propget, helpcontext(0x00001234)]
        BSTR Name();
        [id(0x76543210), propput, helpcontext(0x00001234)]
        void Name([in] BSTR* rhs);
        // ...
};

// From "interface Document":
[
  odl,
  uuid(AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-111111111111),
  helpcontext(0x00001111),
  dual,
  oleautomation
]
interface Document : BaseObject {
    // No member description for the 'Name' property.
};

// From "dispinterface BaseObject":
[
  uuid(AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-222222222222),
  helpcontext(0x00002222),
  dual
]
dispinterface BaseObject {
    properties:
    methods:
        // ...
        [id(0x76543210), propget, helpcontext(0x00001234)]
        BSTR Name();
        [id(0x76543210), propput, helpcontext(0x00001234)]
        void Name([in] BSTR* rhs);
        // ...
};

// From "interface BaseObject":
[
  odl,
  uuid(AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-222222222222),
  helpcontext(0x00002222),
  dual,
  oleautomation
]
interface BaseObject : BaseDispatch {
    // ...
    [id(0x76543210), propget, helpcontext(0x00001234)]
    HRESULT Name([out, retval] BSTR* oNameBSTR);
    [id(0x76543210), propput, helpcontext(0x00001234)]
    HRESULT Name([in] BSTR* oNameBSTR);
    // ...
};
```

Comment: It depends on the COM object itself, how it's defined, if it uses IDispatch interfaces or IUnknown-derived interface, if the object has a type library (.TLB or .DLL embedding one) or not, if you defined interface manually in C#, etc. If the object Difficult to help w/o details, please provide *much more* details. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SimonMourier I've updated my answer. It is difficult to guess what is useful information vs. noise when one doesn't know a topic well (which is my situation with COM, and the reason why I posted here in the first place). Let me know if you're still missing anything.

Comment: If you can import metadata for .NET it means there's a TLB somewhere (we also see there are generated TypeLibType attributes). The problem is often .NET generated code lies from what's really defined by the Fancysoft vendor. Can you find that TLB (in 90% cases, it's embedded in the main fancysoft .DLL (whatever that is), it can also be visible in the .csproj, and open it with OLEView from Windows SDK (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/ole-com-object-viewer), open the .dll or a .tlb from Oleview.

Comment: Thanks @SimonMourier. As mentioned earlier the .type libraries are provided by the Vendor. I edited my question and added what I could find related to the Name property by opening the type library in oleview.exe.

Comment: Ok, it's because the `propput` definition uses a `BSTR*` (a pointer to a BSTR), not a `BSTR`. So the get and set are not `compatible` and .NET does what it can (ie: build two methods). For example if you change `HRESULT Name([in] BSTR* oNameBSTR);` into `HRESULT Name([in] BSTR oNameBSTR);` and rebuild a TLB, .NET will generate a nice and cozy `Name {get;set;}` property. It works, but it's a clunky IDL design.

Comment: @SimonMourier I have tested your solution by modifying the interop library itself (using ildasm/ilasm) and so far it works like a charm, thanks a bunch! Still, I can't help but wondering how a systematic edit of the auto-generated C# glue code can be a silver bullet. Can you think of any scenario where modifying the setter signature like this could cause some runtime error?

Comment: You mean a patched .NET setter (proput) works w/o changing the implementation (which is vendor-provided) just modifying the .NET metadata? It's surprising, probably does so because it only relies on IDispatch vendor-implemention which may be coded so it understand BSTR and BSTR* in a generic way. You're lucky if it works :-)