# Unexpected error when assiging COM object to a C# 'dynamic' variable

Tags: c#, dynamic, com

I am interested in the possibilities offered by the C# *dynamic* keyword, but I am facing unexpected issues.

If I create a default .NET 4.8 template in Visual Studio 2022...

This works:

```cs
dynamic obj = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
obj.Workbooks.Add();
```

This works too:

```cs
object obj1 = Marshal.GetActiveObject("FancySoft.Application");
object obj2 = obj1.GetType().InvokeMember("FancyProperty", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, obj1, null);
```

This fails with a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.'`:

```cs
dynamic obj1 = Marshal.GetActiveObject("FancySoft.Application");
object obj2 = obj1.FancyProperty;
```

Finally, if I add a COM reference to FancySoft to my project, this works as expected:

```cs
var obj1 = (Application) Marshal.GetActiveObject("FancySoft.Application");
var obj2 = obj1.FancyProperty;
```

I have found an [interesting discussion thread](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/net/how-to-get-acadapplication-from-a-c-assembly-running-in-autocad/m-p/5074520/highlight/true#M40864) that suggests that a Vendor can intentionally restrict the use of the *dynamic* keyword in client applications.

In my case, the Vendor doesn't even officially support .NET-based automation scenario (although it is a common scenario in our industry) so I can't ask them for that type of information.

Have you seen this behavior elsewhere?
Am I missing something?
Is there any way to confirm that this behavior is intentional without asking the vendor? (By looking at the .TLB files, using some reflection tricks, etc.?)

Comment: Here is a comprehensive doc to handle your issues. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/exposing-com-components

Comment: `dynamic` mostly (it not entirely) uses `IDispatch` ("aka late binding" which is name-based), and yes this is completely possible that it doesn't work. I doubt it's intentional, more a bad interface design, as demonstrated in other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77478817/cs1545-error-with-specific-com-object-properties

Comment: @SimonMourier I wrote a minimal vbscript tonight, which works as expected with the Name property from that other post. That should too be using IDispatch right? If so why a different behavior?

Comment: Well vbscript internals are not the same as .net internals, there are many ways to use IDispatch. Difficult to say more w/o a reproducing COM object to test this specific IDispatch by myself

Comment: Thanks @SimonMourier, I learn a lot with every answer. Unfortunately it is highly unlikely that you have access to this program. I just tried the same example in a VB.NET project, and the property can be accessed as one would expect (regardless whether obj1 is defined as an Object or an Application). I would have thought the behavior in VB would be closer to C#, but that's apparently not the case.